# how to calculate coverage of each base of mapped reads?

Tags: rna, coverage, awk

I have a RNA aligned file without any header info. 
I need to calculate the coverage of each mapped base for per chromosome. Is it possible to do it with perl ?

```
NS500377:28:H16A7BGXX:2:21205:16038:7658        99      chr2   3000482 255     46M     =       3000502 56      GTCCTACAGTGTGCATTTCTCGTTTTCCACGTTTCT    AAAA)FFFFFFFFFAFFFFFFFFFFF.F.FFFFFAF    XA:i:2  MD:Z:21T4T7T1   NM:i:3
NS500377:28:H16A7BGXX:3:11503:24953:10427       99      chr2   3000482 255     50M     =       3000513 71      GTCCTACAGTGTGCATTTCTCATTTTTCAAGTTTTTCAGT        AAAAAFFFFFFFFFFFFAFFFFFF7AAFFFFFFFFFFFFF
        XA:i:1  MD:Z:21T7C10    NM:i:2
NS500377:28:H16A7BGXX:3:12404:23929:9392        163     chr2   3000482 255     49M     =       3000483 40      GTCCTACAGTGTGCATTTCCCTTTTTTCACGTTTTTTAG AAFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF XA:i:1  MD:Z:19T16C2    NM:i:2
NS500377:28:H16A7BGXX:3:12404:23929:9392        83      chr2   3000483 255     49M     =       3000482 -40     TCCTACAGTGTGCATTTCCCTTTTTTCACGTTTTTTAGT AFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF XA:i:2  MD:Z:18T16C3    NM:i:2
NS500377:28:H16A7BGXX:3:21606:15675:1639        83      chr2   3000483 255     50M     =       3000480 -43     TCTTACAGTGTGCATTTCTCTTTTTTCACGTTTTTCAGTG        AFFFFFFFFFAFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFAAAAA
        XA:i:0  MD:Z:2C37       NM:i:1
NS500377:28:H16A7BGXX:4:12605:18505:11088       83      chr2   3000486 255     50M     =       3000481 -45     TACAATGTGCATTTCTCTTTTTTCACGTTTTTCAGTATTT        FFFFFFFAFFF)FFFFFFFFF<FFFF<AFFFFFFFAA<AA
        XA:i:1  MD:Z:4G31G3     NM:i:2
NS500377:28:H16A7BGXX:2:13303:20634:12085       99      chr2   3000487 255     49M     =       3000521 73      ACAGTGTACATTTCTCATTTTTCACGTTTTTCAGTGTTA AAAAAFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF. XA:i:2  MD:Z:7G8T21T0   NM:i:3
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for `bedtools genomecov`, specifically [`-d`](https://bedtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/content/tools/genomecov.html#d-reporting-per-base-genome-coverage) option. See https://bedtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/content/tools/genomecov.html , for example:

```
bedtools genomecov -i A.bed -g my.genome -d
```

---

I recommend not reinventing the wheel: use `bedtools` instead of reimplementing the same functionality in Perl.

Comment: thanks, but bedtools doesn't work in this case as there is no header info.

Comment: Can you add it from another bam file using samtools? Or add a fake header?

Comment: i did add a header from a different sample to calculate the coverage... just wondering if we can do it using awk.